# Is there any way to communicate between Flutter and Javascript continuously on scrolling or other actions performed in Webview Flutter?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, webview

In my Flutter project, I am using **WebView** to load one html page which includes some **Javascript** functions. I have created some functions in **Javascript** file to communicate with Flutter and I call those functions from my Flutter main.dart class like below:

```
        body: FutureBuilder<String>(
            future: _initServer,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                // while data is loading:
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else {

                final url = snapshot.data;

                return WebView(
                  initialUrl: url,
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {

                    _controller.complete(webViewController);
                    _controller2 = webViewController;

                  },

                  onProgress: (int progress) {

                    showAlert(context, _controller2!);
                    print('WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)');
                  },
                  javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>{

                    _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
                  
                  },
                  navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
                    if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
                      print('blocking navigation to $request}');
                      return NavigationDecision.prevent;
                    }
                    print('allowing navigation to $request');
                    return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                  },
                  onPageStarted: (String url) {
                    print('Page started loading: $url');
                  },
                  onPageFinished: (String url) {
                    print('Page finished loading: $url');
                    _toasterJavascriptChannel(context);

                  },
                  gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0x00000000),

                );
              }
            }),

      ),
    );
  }

  JavascriptChannel _toasterJavascriptChannel(BuildContext context) {
    return JavascriptChannel(
        name: 'flutterChannel',
        onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
          // ignore: deprecated_member_use
         print('###MSG: ${message.message}');
        });
  }


  void showAlert(BuildContext context, WebViewController controller) async{
    await controller.runJavascript('window.AppComponent.makeAlert("$sendMsg")');
  }
```

The **showAlert** function is called perfectly and **Javascript** message receive through channel also works.

**But The problem is**- these functions are called only once the **webview** is loaded. But I need a solution to communicate continuously with the JS (for example, if the user scrolls or highlight) to track every event performed by the user.

Comment: You can send messages from anywhere in the JavaScript code to Flutter using `flutterChannel.postMessage('...')`. You have to add event listeners etc. in your JS code to every desired place.

Comment: Actually that was not my question, I wanted to know whether it's possible to communicate(calling functions) continuously from flutter webview?

Comment: As far as I know your only option is to send messages with `postMessage`, you can't directly call Flutter Dart functions from webview. You have to catch these messages  in `onMessageReceived` and you can call Flutter Dart functions from there.  How the messages are triggered is up to the JavaScript code running in the webview.